# Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects for local wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I recently moved a wordpress site from a server to my local environment, and I am getting the following error when I try to access the wordpress site locally on my computer:

---

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at `http://localhost:8888/folder/site/` has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

---

However I’m able to go to `http://localhost:8888/folder/site/wp-admin` locally and login and see the backend of the wordpress site.

These are the steps I took to get the wordpress site from the server to my computer:

- I imported in the MySQL database for the wordpress site locally.

  - I changed the siteurl to `http://localhost:8888/folder/site/` in the wpkapi_options table in phpMyAdmin.
- I copied and pasted all the files from the server locally into a folder called folder/site/
- I edited the following things in the wp-config.php file :

  define('DB_NAME', 'localdb');

  define('DB_USER', 'root');

  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

I then went to `localhost:8888/folder/site/` and saw the error above. I proceeded to try the following things to try to resolve this error:

I cleared all my cookies, but that didn’t work. I tried a different browser, but that didn’t work.

```
I changed the siteurl in the database from `http://localhost:8888/folder/site/` to `localhost:8888/folder/site/` and then tried `http://www.localhost:8888/folder/site/` but they both didn’t work.
```

I deactivated all the plugins by changing the plugins folder’s name from plugins to aplugins and that didn’t work.

I tried commenting out header(‘Location: ./’); in index.php and that didn’t work.

I even tried commenting out the following in the org_1.htaccess file but that didn’t work:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I had the same issues, Make sure you have added the new database user with the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a complete WP noob so bear that in mind.  I read that in the wp-config.php file one could change the prefix for database tables from 'wp' to anything so I changed it to 'tbl'.

Not too much time after that, I started getting "too many redirects" in FireFox and a "this page has a redirect loop" in Chrome.  IE would not display - no error.

I cleared cookies per FireFox and started digging.  So I changed the table prefix back to "wp" (the last config type change that I made), saved the change, and stopped getting the redirect.

I recognize that this doesn't speak directly to your issue but I found it interesting that a "simple" change resulted in something so unexpected.